# react native ios willPresentNotification function doesn't handle push notification in the foreground

Tags: ios, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to handle react native FCM with react native firebase messaging .
For IOS i added required code to my AppDelegate.m
I added willPresentNotification function to handle push when app is in foreground :

```
//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
{
  completionHandler(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge);
}
```

Currently i'm not receiving push in the foreground and i want to handle this natively.
Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, a remote push notification will not be displayed when the app is in `foreground`

You have to add `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...
    UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
    center.delegate = self;
    // ...
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {
   [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
}


- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

And in `AppDelegate.h` add `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Another approach is to use the same remote notification and present it as a localNotification [like this](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#local-notifications)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did exactly what you show in your code, i receive the push in the background, but not in the foreground for IOS